# how to fetch multiple managed objects from a single managedobjectcontext

Tags: xcode5

for example say you have Fourweeler and Twoweeler two nsmanagedobjects in a single managedobjectcontext, then how to write fetch request query to retrieve these two objects at the samtime.

Comment: Please read this on how to write a question so others can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask As it is it's impossible to tell you anything because you don't indicate what language this is for, what you have tried, or any code at all.

Answer (score 0):

A fetch request can only retrieve one entity at a time. If you have two unrelated entities then you need to create two fetch requests. If your entities have a relationship you can use a single fetch request and access entity2 via entity1.relationship and vice versa.

In the simplest form a fetch request returns an array of objects in random order (in this case we have a single entity called Event with an attribute called timeStamp):

```
// create a fetch request
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// fetch all objects
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&amp;error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Houston, we have a problem: %@", error);
}

// display all objects
for (Event *event in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [event.timeStamp description]);
}
```

To order your managed objects you can add sort descriptors. If you don't need all objects you can add a predicate to filter which managed objects are added to the array. Take a look at the code snippets in Xcode for such examples (the code above is based on a code snippet).